# How can I apply css rules for specific page scaling level?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid, where each block is **50%** width on small screens and 25% width on 1200px and below. The visitor view the page on the 1366px resolution and with the scale factor of 125%. With this scaling, the grid displays in two columns. Is there a way to display it in 4 columns for 1366px / 125%, while leaving 2 columns for 1200- (e.g. 1170) and 100% scale factor?

HTML:

```
<div class="tiles">
    <a href=""><p>Item 1</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 1"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 2</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 2"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 3</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 3"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 4</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 4"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 5</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 5"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 6</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 6"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 7</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 7"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 8</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 8"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 9</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 9"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 10</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 10"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 11</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 11"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 12</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 12"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 13</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 13"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 14</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 14"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 15</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 15"></a>
    <a href=""><p>Item 16</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Item 16"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0;
}
.tiles {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.tiles a {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 10px 5px;
}
.tiles img {
    width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .tiles a {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/exunreal/pen/gLaYxK

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

You only need to add the class .col-sm-4 for small size column (see documentation size of sizes here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). Also, there is col-lg-4, col-xs-4 for another screen sizes.

It's important to understant that the 100% = 12, for example:

col-lg-12

I expect this help you.